# Files Array is not arriving at upload.php

Tags: forms, file

i've got the following form

```
<form action="http://test.mysideurl.de/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" id="MyUploadForm" >
<input name="file[]" type="file" class="file" multiple>
```

This form should send multiple files (if selected) to upload.php which looks like follows:

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
  $file_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
  $tmp_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $doc_id=process_image($file_name,$tmp_name,$doc_id);
}
```

console of firefox says:

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **...myurl...** on line **15**

Has anyone an idea, why it doesn't receive the files array?

Best regards Daniel

Comment: Update: the html part contains a iframe with name "upload-target" which i have forgotten to post... the form is send to the iframe.

Comment: I've updated the upload.php code like this:

Comment: if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
 foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
  $file_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
  $tmp_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
  echo $file_name."<br>".$tmp_name;
  //Bild verarbeiten
  //if ($doc_id=="") {
   //$doc_id=$_GET["doc_id"];
  //}
  //$doc_id=process_image($file_name,$tmp_name,$doc_id);
 }
} else {
 echo "nothing arrived!"; 
}

Comment: And i get "nothing arrived" so definitely no files arrive at upload.php